# I wants that firebase RTDB should send value of key whenever there will be change in values

Tags: firebase, arduino-esp8266

I have been working on a arduino  project based on firebase real time database. My task is to monitor change in values of KEYS . I am able to read KEYS from arduino but to do this I am reading KEYS in a loop but this increases my data traffic, which I dont want to do( Google gives 10 GB of free data for RTDB).
I want this process in such a way that whenever there will be change in KEY'S value firebase should inform my controller that values have been changed . By doing this I can avoid reading KEY again and again and this way I can save Data traffic.
Please help me if there is any efficient way to get to know change in KEYs values.

Comment: How do you connect to the Realtime Database? Via an SDK or via the REST API?

Comment: i am using this library https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266 to connect to firebase and doing read and write activity.

Comment: That documentation states **Supports database read, store, update, delete and value changes listener** so, have you investigated how to implement the changes listener?

Comment: @Jay i tried but could not find the correct solution , actually i am a newbie on firebase, could you help me ?

Comment: Sure. I would first suggest reviewing the documentation at this link [Server Data Changes Listener with Server-Sent Events or HTTP Streaming](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266#server-data-changes-listener-with-server-sent-events-or-http-streaming). Then getting to the example code which start with *The following example showed how to subscribe to the data changes* I would copy and paste that code, modifying where necessary, into a test project and see what happens. But I also think @RenaudTarnec provided that same info in an answer, which should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the [Firebase-ESP8266 library](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266), you need to use the technique described in the ["Server Data Changes Listener with Server-Sent Events or HTTP Streaming"](https://Server%20Data%20Changes%20Listener%20with%20Server-Sent%20Events%20or%20HTTP%20Streaming) section of the documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266/tree/master/examples out of this examples which one will be helpful for me ?

Comment: I guess the first one but it depends on your data model.